# PHP Mail - Sometimes sends blank email

Tags: php, html, email

I am new at coding! I created a html form sending emails via mail.php. It is working perfectly but I receive (only) sometimes blank email...

- In order to avoid this problem, I created a Javascript control of the fields in order to avoid this problem. I tested the script and it is working well on the main Internet browsers.
- I checked similar problems in various threads but everything seems correct.

mail.php code

```
<?php
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$solicitud = $_POST['solicitud'];
$interes = $_POST['interes'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$vehiculo = $_POST['vehiculo'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$optin = $_POST['optin'];
$formcontent="Felicidades, tienen un nuevo contacto $interes. \n Nombres: $nombres \n Apellidos: $apellidos \n Correo: $email \n Teléfono: $phone \n Tipo de solicitud: $solicitud \n Vehículo de interés: $interes \n Ciudad: $ciudad \n Vehículo actual: $vehiculo \n Mensaje: $mensaje \n Optin: $optin";
$recipient = "contact@myemail.com";
$subject = "Nuevo contacto $interes";
$mailheader = "From: $recipient \r\n" . "Reply-To: contact@myemail.com \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: gracias.html");
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
function FillForm() {
var FormName = "form1";
var questionlocation = location.href.indexOf('?');
if(questionlocation < 0) { return; }
var q = location.href.substr(questionlocation + 1);
var list = q.split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   var kv = list[i].split('=');
   if(! eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0])) { continue; }
   kv[1] = unescape(kv[1]);
   if(kv[1].indexOf('"') > -1) {
      var re = /"/g;
      kv[1] = kv[1].replace(re,'\\"');
      }
   eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0]+'.value="'+kv[1]+'"');
   }
}
FillForm();
//-->
</script>
```

I do not manage to understand why sometimes I receive messages which are perfect and sometimes empty messages.

Comment: Can you post the form and javascript also?

Comment: If this is all your code in `mail.php` then whenever this page is loaded it will send an email, regardless of whether the source data is present or not. There are many thing that might try to load mail.php, ranging from the 'innocent' (e.g. web index crawlers like Google) to the malicious, looking for ways to break into your server, or use it to send spam. Your PHP code should check that it has meaningful data before sending the email.

Comment: Are you using a separate page to collect the data and then this page to send the email? AND has the page collecting the data been properly validated before it can be successfully submitted? You haven't given us much to go on. We would have to make assumptions to how you are doing this.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your time and replies. I added in my original post the Javascript code that I am using to validate the data on the html page including the form.

I

Comment: Don't just check the data, check if the request is POST, also check the route